# In Tensorflow.keras 2.0, when a model has multiple outputs, how to define a flexible loss function for model.fit()?

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Let's say here is a model with two outputs.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(35, 7), dtype=tf.float32)     # (None, 35, 7)
net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(11, activation='relu')(x)   # (None, 35, 11)
net = tf.reduce_max(net, axis=1, name='maxpool')        # (None, 11)

a = tf.keras.layers.Dense(13, activation='relu')(net)   # (None, 35, 11)
b = tf.keras.layers.Dense(17, activation='relu')(net)   # (None, 35, 11)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=x, outputs=[a, b])
```

When I do `model.compile(loss=loss_fn, optimizer='sgd')`:
the `model.fit(x=train, y=(label1, label2))` runs `loss_fn` for each pair of output and label (i.e., `loss_fn(a, l1)` and `loss_fn(b, l1)`).

When I do `model.compile(loss=[loss_fn1, loss_fn2], optimizer='sgd')`:
 the `model.fit(x=train, y=(label1, label2))` runs `loss_fn1` for `a` and `loss_fn2` for `b` (i.e., `loss_fn1(a, l1)` and `loss_fn2(b, l1)`).

So, basically it seems to handle outputs individually (paired with given corresponding labels).

**What if I have to define a loss function that should handle/consider both outputs together, and use the function with `model.fit`?**

(One thing I can think of is to concatenate outputs into one tensor, and separate them in a loss function. However, I don't want to go there since two output may not have consistent shape. Instead, is it possible, for example, something like...)

```
def loss_fn(y_true, y_pred):
    # I want to access both output ...
    l1, l2 = y_true
    a, b = y_pred
    # ... do something about loss ...
    return loss
```

Comment: You may concatenate two model outputs into one and do same on the label so that you have one output. Afterwards, you can do whatever you want in the loss function.

Comment: @bit01, sorry you already mentioned the right answer...

Answer (score 1):

You would concatenate your two Dense layers, and do exactly the same as you mentioned:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

i = Input((10,))
x = Dense(10)(i)
a = Dense(3, use_bias=False)(x)
b = Dense(3, use_bias=False)(x)
# Now you concatenate both outputs,
# so nothing happens to them
c = Concatenate()([a,b])
m = Model(i, c)

def loss(y_true, y_pred):
    # Do your loss on your subset
    a, b  = y_pred[:, :3], y_pred[:, 3:]
    # Do something random
    return K.mean(a*b)

m.compile("adam", loss)

m.fit(np.random.random((10, 10)),
      np.random.random((10, 6)))

# Outputs:
# 10/10 [=======] - 0s 22ms/sample - loss: -0.2251
```

edit; haven't seen that actually @bit01 commented already the to go approach